# Pytorch DataLoader for custom dataset

Tags: python, pytorch, dataloader, pytorch-dataloader

I am trying to write a custom data loader for a dataset where the directory structures is as follows:

```
All_data
|
->Numpy_dat
| |
|  -> dat_0
|      -> dat_{0}_{0}.npy
|      .
|      .
| -> dat_1
|      -> dat_{0}_{0}.npy
|      -> dat_{0}_{1}.npy
|      .
|      .
|->mask_numpy
  |
  -> mask_0
     -> mask_{0}_{0}.npy
     -> mask_{0}_{1}.npy
     .
     .
  -> mask_1
     -> mask_{0}_{0}.npy
     -> mask_{0}_{1}.npy
     .
     .
```

I am new to pytorch and was finding the tutorials difficult to follow for get item of the loader.

Comment: Are these images? The mask are in what format? Are the files in `mask_0` for one item or one item each? Please give more details on the structure of your dataset.

Comment: These are numpy matrices, and the mask is available for each corresponding data matrix. So for each file in `dat_0` there is a corresponding mask in `mask_0`. I want to load them all without resizing but for each image in dat_0 I wish to do overlapping windows and random crop. Hope this helps.

Comment: And why there are sub-folders (such as `dat_0`), do they have a particular meaning?

Comment: Yes, each dat_0 or dat_{i} is a different of alteration to the same data. So suppose I have an image of a monkey, which forms my base. Then dat_0 will have a monkey with banana and dat_1 is monkey with cycle so on and so forth. The data in dat_0 is a the monkey with banana image sliced into i times j non-overlapping boxes. And I want to create overlapping windows for each file in dat_0. Hope this helps.

Comment: So your model trains on image patches only? There is no need to reassemble all the patches?

Comment: Yes, there is no need to reassemble the patches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would look like this:

```py
import numpy
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from pathlib import Path


class MyDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, folder: str) -> None:
        super().__init__()

        self.folder = Path(folder).expanduser().resolve()
        self.patches =self.folder.glob("**/dat_*.npy")

    def __getitem__(self, index: int) -> tuple[torch.Tensor, torch.Tensor]:
        patch_path = self.patches[index]  # `folder/Numpy_dat/dat_z/dat_x_y.npy`

        patch_id = patch_path.name.split("_", maxsplit=1)[1]  # 'x_y.npy'
        sub_folder_id = patch_path.parent.name.split("_", maxsplit=1)[1]  # 'z'
        mask_path = self.folder

        # `folder/mask_numpy/mask_z/mask_x_y.npy`
        mask_path = self.folder / Path(
            "mask_numpy", f"mask_{sub_folder_id}", f"mask_{patch_id}"
        )

        patch = numpy.load(patch_path)
        mask = numpy.load(mask_path)

        return torch.from_numpy(patch), torch.from_numpy(mask)


def main():
    dataset = MyDataset(folder="All_data")

    for patch, mask in dataset:
        print(patch.shape, mask.shape)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The key part is to first list all the patch filenames and store them in the dataset object. Then, you implement the `__getitem__` method which returns a pair of (patch, mask) tensors. The bulk of the code is to derive the correct mask filename from the patch name. You finally read the Numpy matrices and convert them to PyTorch tensors before returning them.

I suggest you to improve your database structure. You do not need the sub-folders if the image id (the number identifying the image the patch correspond to) is part of the filename. From there, if you simplify further and use the same name for the patch and the mask such as:

```
data
  patches
    patch_0_0.npy
    patch_0_1.npy
    patch_1_0.npy
    patch_1_1.npy
    ...
  masks
    patch_0_0.npy
    patch_0_1.npy
    patch_1_0.npy
    patch_1_1.npy
    ...
```

then, this greatly simplifies the dataset logic:

```py
class MyDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, folder: str) -> None:
        super().__init__()

        self.patches_folder = Path(folder, "patches").expanduser().resolve()
        self.masks_folder = Path(folder, "masks").expanduser().resolve()

        self.patches = list(self.patches_folder.glob("*.npy"))

    def __getitem__(self, index: int) -> tuple[torch.Tensor, torch.Tensor]:
        patch_path = self.patches[index]
        mask_path = self.masks_folder / patch_path.name
        
        patch = numpy.load(patch_path)
        mask = numpy.load(mask_path)

        return torch.from_numpy(patch), torch.from_numpy(mask)
```

Comment: Hi, could you help with one last thing on how to add a random crop to this? It would be very helpful then I can extend that logic to multiple transformations I plan to add?

Comment: The `__getitem__` method is the place where to put your data augmentation logic. Use torchvision [`RandomCrop`](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/generated/torchvision.transforms.RandomCrop.html#torchvision.transforms.RandomCrop) for this purpose. Because you need to crop both the image and the mask with the same parameters, use `RandomCrop.get_params` and then use the crop `function`.

Comment: I see, thank you. One final question, you initially asked about the ability to reassemble the patches. If suppose I wanted to be able to do that then how would that look like?

Comment: Imagine patches are 2x2 pixels and a full image is 4 patches. you would create an empty tensor `full = torch.empty(size=(2 * 2, 2 * 2))` and then assign it the first patch `full[:2, :2] = patch1` (upper-left), etc, then the last one `full[2:4, 2:4] = patch4` (bottom-right). You would do than using two nested for-loops of course and correctly manage the indices. Open a new question though, comments are not meant for extended discussion.

Comment: Posted a new comment here (https://stackoverflow.com/q/75630836/10977868). Thanks!

Comment: Hi I am unable to use dataloader once I made a few modifications to include transforms in this. Could you help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/75745911/10977868

Comment: You deleted the last question, did you solved your issue?

Comment: Yes, I did solve it. Forgot about deleting it from here. I am getting a lot of issues as this is my first time building a model. Thanks for following up though!